# Word found unreadable content error when opening file

Tags: c#, openxml, asp.net-core-2.1, openxml-sdk, memorystream

I am facing an error "**Word found unreadable content in abc.docx. Do you want to recover the content of this document?**" while opening the Word (.docx) file.

I have tried with all the solutions given on the Internet but no success on this. Below is my code for writing the content into the stream.

```cs
private void test()
        {
            using (MemoryStream one = await db.DownloadFile("templates", "one.docx"))
            {
                using (MemoryStream two = await db.DownloadFile("templates", "two.docx"))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream newStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        one.CopyTo(newStream);
                        editingMemoryStream.Position = 0;

                        using (WordprocessingDocument mainDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(one, true))
                        {
                            using (WordprocessingDocument newDoc =
                                WordprocessingDocument.Open(newStream, true))
                            {
                                Generate(modal, new, main, report);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
private void Generate(List<modal> mo, WordprocessingDocument new, MemoryStream report)
 {
     var main = new.MainDocumentPart;
     modal = mo[0];

     AddTableToBody(report, modal.table, mo);        
  }

public void AddTableToBody(MemoryStream temp, dailyReport,
                    MainDocumentPart main)
   {
            using (WordprocessingDocument newDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(editingMemoryStream, true))
            {
                WP.Body body= dailyReport.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                var main = dailyReport.MainDocumentPart;
                //* some code is here*//

                var clone = dailyReport.CloneNode(true);
                main.Document.Body.AppendChild(new WP.Paragraph(new WP.Run(clone)));
                main.Document.Save();
            }
        }
```

The file contains 2 tables with some labels.

Comment: And when you let Word open the document can it? If yes, save that to a different file name. Open the first ("bad") document in the Open XML Productivity Tool. Then use its "Compare" feature to open the file Word repaired. This will generate code that shows how to create the second from the first, which should show you your mistake. Or simply open the repaired file in the Tool which will generate the code to create that document, and you can compare that to your code.

Comment: Yes, If I choose yes, than it opens. Okay let me try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like you are adding a `w:body` element (`Body` instance) to a `w:r` element (`Run` instance) in the following two lines of code:

```cs
var clone = dailyReport.CloneNode(true);
main.Document.Body.AppendChild(new WP.Paragraph(new WP.Run(clone)));
```

In the above excerpt, `clone` is a `Body` instance (`w:body` element) with all its child elements. I can only assume `parent` is the `MainDocumentPart` of some other `WordprocessingDocument`. You are appending a new `Paragraph` (`w:p`) with one `w:r` (`Run`) and one `w:body` (`Body`) with whatever children the latter has. This is invalid Open XML and most probably the reason why Word complains.

Comment: Yes, Parent is MainDocumentPart. Actually I have two different templates and I have to append both templates.

Comment: The important piece here is “other WordprocessingDocument”, because it is clear that it is a MainDocumentPart. So, if you provide snippets or examples, you should make sure the code can be understood and does not leave out important details. With your example, nobody can understand what you are trying to do. I just saw that you are adding a Body to a Run, which is wrong in any case. If my answer was helpful, please upvote. If it solved your problem, please accept as the answer. If it didn’t solve it, please provide more information.

Comment: I have edit and provide more information about my code.

Comment: @Amitbalaji, your updated code still does not make sense. You have not changed the fact that you are adding a `Body` to a `Run` as pointed out by my answer. You can't add a `Body` to a `Run`, so you must change that. Secondly, in your `AddTableToBody` method, you don't have access to `editingMemoryStream`, but you are opening a `WordprocessingDocument` on the stream. Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example? Or fix your code as suggested by my answer and see whether that solves it.